# TDengine JDBC can find method setTimestamp()

Tags: java, database

I am using TDEngine on my project. Recently, after upgrading TDengine from version 2.1.2.0 to 2.1.3.0. I found the mistake bellow, I could't connect to the TDengine with taosJDBC. My taos-jdbc version 2.0.22  os:ubuntu 18.4.

```
get connection starting...
java.library.path:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: setTimestamp
    at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBJNIConnector.initImp(Native Method)
    at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBJNIConnector.init(TSDBJNIConnector.java:74)
    at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBDriver.connect(TSDBDriver.java:121)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at com.taosdata.example.JDBCDemo.init(JDBCDemo.java:42)
    at com.taosdata.example.JDBCDemo.main(JDBCDemo.java:21)
```

Comment: By the way, the terrible class `java.sql.Timestamp` was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. Specifically for database access: `OffsetDateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

I have meet this mistake last week, after upgrading I cannot connect to the TDengine server though taos-jdbc. This is because TDengine starting support nanosecond from version 2.1.3.0. However,taos-jdbc is not compatibily with high version of tdengine，you need upgrade taos-JDBC to version 2.0.31 or higher.